# How to define a sequence in the get function?

Tags: r

Let say, I have these objects:

```
v1=11:12; v2=13:14; v3=15:16
```

I can combine them using one of these 2 ways:

```
combined = c(); for(i in 1:3) combined=c(combined, get(paste0("v", i)))
# or
combined = c(get(paste0("v", 1)), get(paste0("v", 2)), get(paste0("v", 3)))
```

Isn't the 2nd way more efficient if I have many vectors, each with thousands of elements? Is there any way of defining the sequentiality in the 2nd way?

Thanks

Comment: The proper solution is to put these vectors together in a list when you create them. You should not have many objects (and especially many related vectors) free-floating in your global environment and thus never need `get`. In your office you also use folders and binders. Or do you just dump all paperwork on your desk?

Comment: Thank you Roland. Either a list or a vector, I'm trying to avoid the cost of updating, and make the list or the vector at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mget()` to define multiple object names and use `unlist()` to convert to a single vector

```
v1=11:12; v2=13:14; v3=15:16
combined = unlist(mget(paste0("v", 1:3)), use.names = F)
```

Just update `use.names = T` if you want a the resulting combined vector with named elements.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mget` to return the values of all the objects ( of strings 'v1', 'v2', 'v3') in a `list` and then concatenate with `do.call`

```
do.call(c, mget(paste0("v", 1:3)))
```

This can also be constructed with `ls`

```
do.call(c, mget(ls(pattern = "^v\\d+")))
```